# Androgenic hair по-русски

Tags: перевод

Подозреваю, что *[Androgenic hair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Androgenic_hair)* переводится на русский как «андрогенное оволосение», но не могу найти ни одной словарной статьи с таким словосочетанием.

Comment: Хотел тэг `мединица`.

Comment: "Оволосение тела" скорее всего. На Вики в статье [Человек разумный](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) есть такая фраза: "Кроме того, взрослым мужчинам свойственно более сильное оволосение лица и тела."

Comment: @YellowSky, речь именно о том оволосении, что является вторичным половым признаком.

Comment: Оволосение по мужскому типу

Comment: @Nakilon Не надо тэга `мединица`, тэг `медицина` назначил — хай будет, коли считаете нужным.

Comment: @Anixx Ничего подобного! Здесь не об мужском типе, у женщин тоже _androgenic hair_.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov, я не завсегдатай этого сайта, но предположил, что возможна тэгизация по такому же типу, как разделяют словари, ибо сфера употребления многое значит.

Answer (score 3):

В контексте статьи, чью ссылку вы предоставили, это переводится как "андрогенные волосы" или, в разговорном варианте, "волосы на теле". Сам термин "androgenic hair" не зависит от пола и относится к волосам на теле как мужчин, так и женщин.

Answer (score 3):

В приведенной Вами статье речь идет не о вторичном половом признаке, а вообще обо всех сравнительно длинных, "полноценных" волосах на теле (в отличие от волос на голове и от пушковых волос, которыми покрыто все тело практически с рождения). У обоих полов они растут под влиянием гормонов андрогенов, отсюда и название "androgenic". Эти гормоны есть как у мужчин, так и у женщин. У обоих полов они начинают вырабатываться корой надпочечников (а не половыми органами) в самом-самом начале полового созревания. Позже у мужчин они начинают вырабатываться также яичками (в большом количестве) а у женщин - яичниками (в маленьком количестве). В результате у мужчин их получается больше, поэтому и волос на теле тоже больше. В контексте данной статьи, перевод "оволосение по мужскому типу" вряд ли можно считать правильным, потому что там говорится про явление роста волос на теле под влиянием андрогенов в целом, у обоих полов. По-русски эти волосы, похоже, не принято называть "андрогенными". Думаю, можно написать просто "волосы на теле", или, возможно, "оволосение тела", но насчет последнего не уверена.

Answer (score 0):

"Оволосение по мужскому типу".
Для мужчин - физиологическая норма, для женщин либо индивидуальная особенность, либо симптом какого-либо заболевания. Обычно сильно беспокоит женщин.

Comment: Пожалуйста, раскройте свой ответ, приведите какие-то ссылки. Вот цитата из википедии - Body hair, or androgenic hair, is the terminal hair that develops on the human body during and after puberty. It is differentiated from the head hair and less visible vellus hair, which are much finer and lighter in color.  - то есть не совсем очевидно, при чём тут мужской тип.

Comment: Оказалось, что авторы тех статей, из которых я сделала вывод, вовсе не носители языка, а один турок, второй японец. Моя ошибка, запомнила выражение.